# Count number of isosceles triangles in a set of points

Tags: c++, computational-geometry

Given a set of points, what is the number of isosceles triangles that can be formed with the combinations of all points in the set?

It is certain that 3 collinear points never exists in the set.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned long long llu;

typedef struct {
    llu x,y;
}point_t;

inline llu distance_p(point_t &p1,point_t &p2)
{
    return (p2.x - p1.x)*(p2.x - p1.x) + (p2.y - p1.y)*(p2.y - p1.y);
}

int main(void){
    llu n;
    point_t ps[1000];
    while (scanf("%llu",&n), n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            scanf("%llu %llu",&ps[i].x,&ps[i].y);

        llu ans = 0;
        for (llu i = 0,a,b,c; i < n; ++i) {
            for (llu j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
                for (llu k = j + 1; k < n; ++k) {
                    a = distance_p(ps[i], ps[j]);
                    b = distance_p(ps[j], ps[k]);
                    c = distance_p(ps[k], ps[i]);

                    //at least two side equals
                    if(a == b || b == c || c == a){
                        ++ans;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%llu\n",ans);
    }
}
```

But this is slow: \$O(n^3)\$. How can I improve my code?

Answer (score 9):

## Try another algorithm

Instead of considering triangles, you could simply consider lines starting from a point.

For each point, compute the distance between *this point* and *every other point*; you will get a number of distances.

Now, for every distance from a point, count the number \$n\$ of equal distances, and add \$n*(n-1)/2\$ to the number of isoceles triangles. If you use an [`std::unordered_map<unsigned long long, unsigned>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) to count the number of occurrences of every distance from a point, it should give you a \$O(n^2)\$ algorithm, if I'm not mistaken.

**Note:** this method might count the same triangle several times if a triangle happens to be equilateral. Unfortunately, I don't see a simple way to circumvent this problem.

## C++ pedantry

I talked about the math first since it's what really matters, but honestly, your C++ isn't the prettiest C++ around, so here we go for the C++ review:

- Please don't use `typedef unsigned long long llu;`. Even if it's long to write, `llu` doesn't convey any meaning to anyone reading it. Type the full name and people will know out-of-the-box what type they are using.
- `distance_p` looks like it computes the *distance* between `p1` and `p2`, but it actually computes the the *squared distance* between them. Make that clear by naming the function `squared_distance`.
- Also, `distance_p` does not alter its parameter. Therefore, pass `const` references instead of simple ones:

  ```
  inline unsigned long long squared_distance(const point_t &p1, const point_t &p2)
  {
      return (p2.x - p1.x)*(p2.x - p1.x) + (p2.y - p1.y)*(p2.y - p1.y);
  }
  ```
- You don't need to use `typedef` like it is done in C to write `point_t` instead of `struct point_t`. In C++, an equivalent `typedef` is done automagically by the compiler. Simply declare your `struct` like this:

  ```
  struct point_t {
      unsigned long long x, y;
  };
  ```
- When using components from the standard library, try to always prefix them with `std::`, even in they come from the C standard library (`std::printf`, `std::scanf`, etc...). Prefixing them may help to avoid name clashes and make it easier to search for standard library components in your code.
- Try not to put everything in `main`. Here, you can easily put the algorithm which looks for isoceles triangles in its own function and let `main` handle only the input & output operations. Splitting code into small logical bricks instead of tightly coupled ones is known as [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

## Putting it all together

Since there are many things to take into account. I decided that I could as well show you how I would have implemented `count_isoceles_triangles` as described using C++11 (that's not exactly how I would have done it, but it's closer to it than what you currently have):

```
struct point_t
{
    unsigned long long x;
    unsigned long long y;
};

unsigned long long squared_distance(const point_t &p1, const point_t &p2)
{
    unsigned long long a = p2.x - p1.x;
    unsigned long long b = p2.y - p1.y;
    return a*a + b*b;
}

template<std::size_t N>
unsigned count_isoceles_triangles(const std::array<point_t, N> points)
{
    unsigned nb_triangles = 0;

    for (const point_t& p1: points)
    {
        std::unordered_map<unsigned long long, unsigned> distances;
        for (const point_t& p2: points)
        {
            unsigned long long dist = squared_distance(p1, p2);
            distances[dist] += 1;
        }

        for (auto&& dist: distances)
        {
            unsigned count = dist.second;
            nb_triangles += count * (count - 1) / 2;
        }
    }

    return nb_triangles;
}
```

Note that there are still some additional differences: I used [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) since it's not *easy* to pass a C array to a function correctly. Also, I didn't check whether `p1 == p2` before counting the distances, but it's also something that should be done.

Comment: It isn't \$(n-1)!\$ that you need to add, it's \$n \choose 2\$, or \$n * (n-1) / 2\$.  Also, you can avoid double counting equilateral triangles by simply not including previously seen vertices when computing the list of all distances for a vertex.

Comment: @JS1 Uh, your formula is indeed the right one, that's what I got for only checking with a small number of points, thanks. That said, I thought of removing the previously visited vertices as well, but a same vertex can be in several isoceles triangles that just happen to share a side, so I don't think that it will work.

Comment: You're right on that second point.  I suppose you could keep a HashMap of triangles created, and check for uniqueness.

Comment: @JS1 Probably, but thay may increase the complexity. We currently store only a count, but now we'd have to store points and check for uniqueness. Well, it might not increase the complexity per se, but it'll be a noticeable constant factor :/